# jQuery auto populate input field based on value from other input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a loan calculator. I was trying to figure out how to auto-populate an interest rate field based loan amount entered.

Here's a sample scenario:

- Amount 0 - 100,000, interest rate = 4.50
- Amount 100,001 - 500,000, interest rate = 4.4
- Amount 500,001 - 1,000,000, interest rate = 4.3
- Amount > 1,000,001, interest rate = 4.0

Here's my markup:

```
<input type="text" size="12" id="loanamount" name="loanamount"/>
<input type="text" size="2" name="tenure" />
<input type="text" size="4" id="interestrate" name="interestrate" disabled/>
```

Hope somebody can help me up.

Thanks.

FD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen for the keyup, calculate the rate, then set the value of the interest rate input:

```
 $("#loanamount").keyup(
   function (e) {
      var loan = $(e.currentTarget).val();
      if (loan <= 100000) {
        $('#interestrate').val('4.5');
      } else if (loan <= 500000) {
        $('#interestrate').val('4.4');
      } else if (loan <= 1000000) {
        $('#interestrate').val('4.3');
      } else if (loan >= 1000001) {
        $('#interestrate').val('4.0');
      } else {
        $('#interestrate').val('');
      }
   }
 );
```

Fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VLZGk/1087/)

Comment: Perfect.

Thanks Mark

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your input field to `keyup` event which fire every time you type something and then get the amount and set the interest rate accordingly

Here is an example:

```
$("loanamount").on( "keyup", function(e){
   var amount = e.target.value;
   var intrestrate = 0;
   if(amount > 0)
     intrestrate = 4.5;
   else
      //... continue with conditions
   $('#interestrate').val(intrestrate);
})
```